# Getting the Namespace in an openshift buildconfig template

Tags: docker, kubernetes, openshift, artifactory

I've been searching and trying to see how I can get the namespace name of the openshift project to append to the build config so I can pass it in as a parameter when generating an image to our jfrog artifactory. Below is a snippet of the buildconfig of what I have

```
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: "${COMPONENT_NAME}"
      env:
        - name: APP_NAMESPACE
          valueFrom:
            fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
```

And withn the same config template I am trying to reference it or use within a url

```
output:
   to:
     kind: DockerImage
     name:
artifactory.example.com/${JFROG_REPO}/$(APP_POD_NAMESPACE)/${COMPONENT_NAME}:${COMPONENT_TAG}
```

I have changed the brackets back and forth from ( to {.

This is the error I'm receiving when deploying through my pipeline

```
spec.output.to.name: Invalid value: "artifactory.example.com/jfrog_repo_name/$(APP_POD_NAMESPACE)/microservice_name:1.0.0": name is not a valid Docker pull specification: invalid reference format
```

Obviously this tells me that it's not able to obtain the environment variable. This template is also being used for Openshift v4.8

Comment: The `env` section sets up environment variables that are available to the build process; they're not going to be available for substitution in other values in the manifest.

Comment: What would be the alternative? I assume some script that's able to find the associated namespace during the build step of the pipeline?